# Embedding Dart into application

Tags: c, embed, dart

I am just experimenting , but want to use Dart as a scripting language for a high performance simulation application I've been working on.(think games)

Basically use Dart in lieu of Lua

I have found old resources, but I have heard the are out of date - and haven't really found any tutorials on how to actually utilize them.

found resources:
https://github.com/google/embed-dart-vm

https://github.com/google/embed-dart-vm/tree/master/src

Comment: Guys, any progress on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any good article on this, only [this discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/qBuKmUBltas/discussion) in Dart group. However, there are working demos in the [Dart's source code](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/runtime/?r=17161#runtime/embedders).

Take a look at [`DartHost`](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/runtime/embedders/openglui/common/dart_host.cc?r=17161) implementation in some of these projects - this should give you some idea about how to do it.