# Is it possible to embed Dart into Java app?

Tags: java, dart

I would like to use **Dart as scripting lang** in my existing Java app. Is it possible to execute Dart code from Java app and if yes what would be the perf penalty for executing Dart script ?

Comment: Are you saying Dart on the front end of like a JSP? Or calling Dart from Java code like you can do with Groovy, et al.?

Comment: @Vidya I mean calling Dart from backend Java app (I'm using Dropwizard   http://www.dropwizard.io/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be (technically) possible.  But it won't be easy.  AFAIK, embedding Dart is a "bleeding edge" activity, and I couldn't anything about embedding in Java.

The Dart runtime is implemented in C, so you have to solve the problem of embedding Dart in classical C code, and *then* the problem of the C <-> Java.

The best I could find was this:  [Embedding Dart into application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016864/embedding-dart-into-application) ... which includes links to sources on the first part of the problem.